# Can't lock tables during Laravel migration

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4, php-7

I need to make a change to a table that results in a very large column being dropped. If I try to drop the column without write locking the table, MySQL will throw the error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '10348300' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: alter table `users` drop `tracking`)
```

However, if I try to put the alteration into a transaction along with `LOCK TABLES` then Laravel fails to migrate with this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1100 Table 'migrations' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
```

Here is my migration statement:

```
\DB::transaction(function () {
    \DB::unprepared("
        LOCK TABLES `users` WRITE;
        ALTER TABLE `users` DROP COLUMN tracking;
        UNLOCK TABLES;"
    );
}, 5);
```

How do I get around this issue?

Comment: Is the `tracking` column part of a PRIMARY or UNIQUE index?